# How to read and and write variables from a .dat file in shell script?

Tags: bash, file, calculation

I have a .dat file of three columns and I want to read that in a .sh file. then I want to calculate something in the .sh file by using those variables.

I have a parameters.dat file like

```
5.6 1.5 9.5 
2.6 5.9 3.9
11.6 13.7 2.1
```

Initially, I was ding the same by generating some random numbers. Now, instead of using the random numbers I want to use an already existing data file to do this.

```
#!/bin/bash


rm scan1.par


for i1 in {1..10..1}

do

 mms1p=$(python -c "import random;print(random.uniform(1, 100))")
 mms2p=$(python -c "import random;print(random.uniform(1, 100))")
 mms3p=$(python -c "import random;print(random.uniform(1, 1000))")


echo mms1p $mms1p >  scan1.par
echo mms2p $mms2p >> scan1.par 
echo mms3p $mms3p >> scan1.par

omg=$(./main scan1.par)

echo $omg >> scan1_result.dat
echo $mms1p $mms2p $mms3p >> scan1_para.dat


done
```

Can you please help me in this matter? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bash is not very appropriate to deal with floating-point numbers. You can use command like the `bc` calculator or even `awk`, but since you already use Python to generate your data file, why not also process your data file with Python?

Comment: Please explain a little bit more what your script does. We should not have trouble to understand your code to help you. I don't understand why you loop `for i1 in {1..10..1}` ?

Comment: I feel like a small transformation should be possible to get your scan1.par file from your parameters.dat file and if you explain the expected scan1.par I'm sure that people will help you in no time.

Comment: @CorentinLimier I am working on a package called micromega which is a c-based package. To execute the main.c file and to get the numerical result I need to have some .par file. This .par file contains all the input values of the parameters. Initially, I was generating the random numbers and to write that in the scan.par file I was using the for-loop. Basically, I was generating 10 random numbers and by using for-loop I was writing those numbers in the scan1.par files one by one.

Comment: I mean, based on the parameter.dat example you gave us, please give the expected scan1.par and scan1_para.dat file.

Comment: Based on the example I gave, the first scan1.par file should look like

    mms1p  5.6
    mms2p 1.5
    mms3p 9.5

Then it will work on ./main scan1.par and will write the results in the scan1_result.dat file and the values of the parameters in the scan1_para.dat file. After that scan1.par file should take the values from the second row and will do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now, instead of using the random numbers I want to use an already existing data file to do this.

Then [read the file line by line, field by field](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r mms1p mms2p mms3p; do
   : your script that uses mms1p mms2p mms3p variables
done < parameters.dat
```

> How to read and and write variables from a .dat file in shell script?

Your method of writing the variables to file is ok. After that read the files line by line, field by field using the same method as above. If you need to read files both at the same time, use ex. `paste scan1_result.dat scan1_para.dat` to marge lines of the files together and then read them line by line field by field.

Comment: Thanks, @Kamil.  This works. However, it is not taking the last row of the parameter.dat file. I mean, suppose my parameter.dat file has 10 rows and it is reading the first 9 rows. I think that is because of some mistake I have made in the script file.